# Jasypt spring boot starter not working with bootstrap.propetites

Tags: jasypt

I have added jasypt spring boot starter 1.18 version in pom as my spring boot version is 1.5.16. I am trying to encrypt bootstrap.properties which is used to access spring cloud config server URL, username and password. The password is in jasypt encrypted format however while connecting to the spring cloud config server it's not sending decrypted value. Does anyone know how to encrypt the value of bootstrap.propetites using Jasypt? I tried all the available options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of jasypt.encryptor.* properties. In latest version which is 3.0.2 as of now jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname is supported however in 1.18 it is not supported (Jasypt [git 1.18](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/tree/jasypt-spring-boot-parent-1.18)). The encrypted password was generated with 3.0.2 version by mistake and decryption was done in 1.18 version hence It was not matching and It was unable to decrypt it. Answer is use the same version for encryption and decryption and always check the properties available in the version which is been used [here](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/tree/master) .It was my bad due to working on parallel microservices which use different version of jasypt!